# URL masking with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

If a visitor of my website open http://www.example.com/pat/to/hi.html, can I show him something different in the address bar with .htaccess, like http://www.example.com only?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Only for this file?

Comment: Hi @Abhishekgurjar, I would like to do for all there is under http://www.example.com/pat/to/

Comment: Can please someone help me, or can suggest something? Thanks